# Reorder the array of objects into specific order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array like this

```
var arr = ["hub","master","hub","transit","transit","master"];
```

I want to reorder the above array into specific order like

```
var arr = ["master","hub","hub","master","transit","transit"];
```

for example, if i get array like

```
Ex1:
var a = ["hub","transit","master","master"];
result = ["master","hub","master","transit"];

Ex2:
var a = ["hub","master"];
result = ["master","hub"];
```

I know that using for loop checking for item in which position and pushing into new array but i want to use more optimized way.

any ideas...thanks

Comment: what is the criteria to rearrange them?

Comment: If it's anything other than alphabetic, first and foremost make sure your code is readable and easy to maintain, rather than optimised.  If/when you objectively prove that that part is slow, _then_ start worrying about optimising it.  JS engines are good at optimising things these days.

Comment: Here is how you should do it. Create simple function: `function reorder(data) { return ["master","hub","hub","master","transit","transit"]; }`.

Comment: the array is dynamic, sometimes all items will be available sometimes wont available but the order should be like that

Comment: You should [edit] your question with that information.  This is more a problem of essentially creating a filtered version of what @dfsq has proposed based on the input data, rather than sorting the input.

Comment: I see your update. The function you should create is like this: `function reorder(data) { if (data.length == 4) return ["master","hub","master","transit"]; if (data.length == 2) return ["master","hub"]; }`. This function will pass the test with what you are asking. So I think this is the solution you are looking for.